# Kialo: How can I view the argument topology map after I have entered an argument

Tags: user-interface

On the online debating platform, Kialo, it is possible to see a high level overview of the discussion, similar to the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwiv6.png) below.

However, once you "enter" a discussion, it seems impossible to get to that diagram again (short of opening up the debate in an Incognito tab). Is it possible to view the diagram in full from within the discussion?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwiv6.png): [image]

Comment: this is a programming q&a exchange site, that question is better asked in the kialo forums

Comment: @FalcoWinkler I don't think there is a kialo forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to see the graph again:

- Click the "i" icon on the thesis (the node on top of all others) of the discussion (next to the heart icon)
- Open the sidebar on the left side with the hamburger-button on the top left. Then click "Info / Stats / Topology"